# R: Hep with regex! - combination of ^, |, \\, _ and $

Tags: regex, r

Below is my R object (x) and some commands that work and some that don't.

```
(x <- c("q10_1", "q10_2", "q10_11", "q12_1", "q12_2", "q13_1", "q13_11"))

# Which strings start with "q10" or "q12? - WORKS
x[grep("^q10|q12", x)]

# Which strings end with "1"? - WORKS
x[grep("1$", x)]

# Which strings end with "_1"? - WORKS
x[grep("\\_1$", x)]

# Which strings start with "q10" AND contain a "1"? - WORKS
x[grep("^q10.+1", x)]

# Which strings start with "q10" AND end with a "_1"? - DOES NOT WORK
x[grep("^q10.+\\_1$", x)]

# Which strings start with "q10" or "q12 AND end with "_1"? - WORKS INCORRECTLY
x[grep("^q10|q12.+\\_1$", x)]
```

Thank you!

Comment: Don't know about 2nd to last, but for your last `0|q` as *single character* 0 or q. If you want q10 or q12 you need `^(q10|q12)`.

Comment: Thank you - it should be ^(q10|q12). This works:x[grep("^(q10|q12).*\\_1$", x)]

Answer (score 2):

Here is all fixed and optimized:

```
x <- c("q10_1", "q10_2", "q10_11", "q12_1", "q12_2", "q13_1", "q13_11")
## Which strings start with "q10" or "q12? - WORKS - FIXED
x[grep("^q1[02]", x)]
## Which strings end with "1"? - WORKS
x[grep("1$", x)]
## Which strings end with "_1"? - WORKS - FIXED
x[grep("_1$", x)]
## Which strings start with "q10" AND contain a "1"? - WORKS - FIXED
x[grep("^q10.*1", x)]
## Which strings start with "q10" AND end with a "_1"? - DOES NOT WORK - FIXED
x[grep("^q10.*_1$", x)]
## Which strings start with "q10" or "q12 AND end with "_1"? - WORKS INCORRECTLY - FIXED
x[grep("^q1[02].*_1$", x)]
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/TkCx8N)

Notes:

- `^q10|q12` can be represented as `^q1[02]` to increase performance and shorten the pattern. This also solves the issue that you had with `^q10|q12` as `q12` was matched anywhere inside the input.
- `\\_1$` - you do not need to escape the underscore
- `^q10.+1` - you need to use a `*` quantifier since there can be `1` right after `q10`
- Same as above issue is with the last 2 expressions. `*` matches 0 or more characters and `+` requires at least 1. Thus, you had no matches.
- The last one - `^q10|q12.+\\_1$` - matches `q10` at the start, and `q12.+_1` at the end, the logic was ruined because of the missing grouping (`^(q10|q12).+\\_1$`), but best is to use `^q1[02].*_1$`.